# bash: how do I convert a hex subnet mask into bit form or the dot-decimal address?

Tags: bash, ip-address, subnet

So far my code will get the IP address from the iOS system and a subnet mask in hex form (`ffffff00`), but I need the subnet address in bit form (24, 23, etc) or binary. How would I do that? I tried converting it with `16#${subnet}` but the number seemed wrong.

Somewhat silly side question - the code doesn't run if the line `echo "hello"` is deleted and I'm not sure why? What role does that line play?

```
if [ $# -ne 0 ]
    echo "hello"
    then
        ip="$(ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\  -f2)"
        subnet="$(ifconfig | grep "netmask " | grep -v 0xff0 | sed -e 's/.*0x\(.*\)broadcast.*/\1/')"
        consub="$((16#${subnet}))"
        echo "$ip $subnet $consub"
exit 0
fi
```

Comment: `if (condition) ; then` is the common syntax. The echo is a statement that allows you to skip the `;` because of silly reasons.

Comment: Also, if you're writing bash scripts with no need for POSIX portability, consider using `[[ .. ]]` for your conditions instead of `[ .. ]`.

Comment: @hack, could you perhaps [add to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47746535/edit) the results you're getting, and the results you'd like to see? It would be helpful in order to evaluate the work we do to create answers. Your question is a great start. It would be even better if it included an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
echo "ffffff00" | perl -pe '$_ = join(".", map(hex, /.{2}/g))'
=> 255.255.255.0

echo "ffffff00" | perl -pe '$_ = unpack("B32", pack("H*", $_)); s/0+$//g; $_ = length'
=> 24
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a reliable way to predict what calculator you'll have on hand in a system running bash (you may have bc or dc or something else), but you don't really need those.  Consider the following function:

```
binary () {
    local n bit=""
    printf -v n '%d' "$1"
    for (( ; n>0 ; n >>= 1 )); do  bit="$(( n&1 ))$bit"; done
    printf '%s\n' "$bit"
}
```

This uses `>>=` to shift bitwise through the input number, then uses `n&1` to evaluate a bitwise AND on that position within the number, and inserting the result into `$bit` for eventual output.

You can put any number in to it:

```
$ binary 123
1111011
$ binary 0xffffff00
11111111111111111111111100000000
```

From there, you should be able to simple count your ones:

```
$ netmask="0xffffff00"
$ bitmask=$( s=$(binary "$netmask"); s="${s%%0*}"; printf '%d' "${#s}" )
$ echo "$bitmask"
24
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but this looks really close to what I'm looking for!! Do you mind explaining what's being done here `for (( ; n>0 ; n >>= 1 )); do  bit="$(( n&1 ))$bit"; done ` - I'm still shaky on bash syntax and I've been trying to read through manuals but what exactly is it looping through with `; n>0 ; n >>= 1` and what is  `$(( n&1 ))$bit` doing? Can you also help explain the bitmask function?

Comment: I'm trying to look up the syntax and read about it, but having trouble piecing the parts together.

Comment: For for loop notation, search the bash man page for `for ((`. Then check the man page under "ARITHMETIC EXPANSION". To see the AND in action, try: `for n in {1..5}; do echo $((n&1)); done`. The AND returns "1" for any odd number. (`1 && 1 == 1`.)

Comment: As for the "stepping through" part... that for loop goes through your number from LSB to MSB, ANDing each bit. See: `x=5; for ((n=$x; n>0; n>>=1)); do echo $((n&1)); done`. The `>>=` just means all the bits in the value get shifted to the right, making the next bit the LSB. The [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr#operators) has some more info. You might want to Google "bit shifting".

Comment: Oh, and "bitmask" is a term for the number you're asking about -- the number of significant bits for the network. So a netmask of `0xfffe0000` is `255.254.0.0` in decimal, and can be represented as a bitmask of `15`, for use in CIDR notation.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the modern `iproute2` tools to get the CIDR instead of parsing `ifconfig`. For example:

```
ip -f inet -o a s scope global |
    grep -Po 'inet \S+' |
    sed 's#.*/\(.*\)#\1#'
```

Comment: I tried other ip commands, and I keep getting an error that says that I don't have the ip command.

Comment: @hack To be honest, in that case I'd recommend finding out which scripting language you've got available by default and writing something small in it to get the netmask out in the format you want. You can do it with a lot of bash, but it's going to be super ugly :( As in: make a mapping for `f, e, c, 8, 0`, to the number of unset bits and sum up for the whole netmask to get a CIDR kind of ugly.

Comment: While I hate to criticize anything that promotes use of `sed`, the OP mentioned this was running in iOS, so both `ip` and `iproute2` are out. It would seem that something small in bash is exactly what the OP is asking for.